# Is there a more elegant way to create several turtles than to write them all out individually?

Tags: python

I'm creating a turtle Screen with several turtles in it, all drawing a different polygon shape. I was wondering how I can make the code for creating the turtles more dense. Now I am writing all four out individually but I'm sure that there is a more legend way to do this. Can someone help me out?

```
equilat = turtle.Turtle()
equilat.color("blue")
equilat.shape("turtle")

square = turtle.Turtle()
square.color("pink")
square.shape("turtle")

hexa = turtle.Turtle()
hexa.color("purple")
hexa.shape("turtle")

octa = turtle.Turtle()
octa.color("grey")
octa.shape("turtle")'
```

Comment: it seems all the  turtle shapes are 'turtles', you can use init to initialise it for all objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension:

```
def build_turtle(color, shape):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.color(color)
    t.shape(shape)
    return t


equilat, square, hexa, octa = [build_turtle(color, "turtle") for color in ("blue", "pink", ...)]
```

Ideally you would have a class, and that `build_turtle` would be the `init` method:

```
class MyTurtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.color(color)
        self.shape("turtle")

equilat, square, hexa, octa = [MyTurtle(color) for color in ("blue", "pink", ...)]
```

Comment: i like the class version

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @iwishicouldcode, consider accepting the answer if you feel is good enough.